# Is there a way to define WPF custom bindings?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

WPF already defines **Binding** and **TemplateBinding**. 
Is there a way to define my own custom binding type.

For example, could I declare a "SelfBinding" where RelativeSource == RelativeSource.Self?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Binding and TemplateBinding are known as [markup extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx) and you can create your own. Also see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) for implementation details.

Edit:You can just inherit from binding making it very simple.

```
public class SelfBinding : Binding
{
    public SelfBinding(string path) : base(path)
    {
        RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self);
    }
}
```